# .match() javascript

Tags: match, javascript

Почему `alert` возвращает только 13 cat_id, хотя должен и 14 уафйукук?

```
var list = '[13, "cat_id"][14, "уафйукук"]';
var tcategories_array_list_match = list.match(/\[(\d+), "(.*?)"\]/i);
alert(tcategories_array_list_match);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var list = '[13, "cat_id"][14, "уафйукук"]';
var tcategories_array_list_match = list.match(/\[(\d+), "(.*?)"\]/g);
alert(tcategories_array_list_match);
```